# Help with Photo app / Gallery

Tags: applications, photos

I deleted the photo app that actually comes pre-installed on Android and have been just using gallery. Is there any way  to download the photo app?

Comment: I thought (but I could **very well** be wrong) that this was part of Google+. Worth uninstalling and reinstalling maybe? I cannot find an apk for it here.

Comment: @RossC only with Kitkat AFAIK. It was a separate app before, and was subject to be split-off again with Lollipop (no safe informations on the latter, though).

Answer (score 0):

You can try "gallerie pro" from the play store. i assume that this is a branch of "the original google Gallery app" - at least on my android 4.2 it looks nearly the same

Answer (score 0):

I did this also, and found an app in the Play Store. It's called Google Photos, but you don't need to search for it that way. Opening the store and typing "photos" will bring it up as the first option. The icon looks exactly the same, so you'll recognize it right away. The download is free and easy.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy 4 running Android 4.1.2. I may be wrong, but I think any phone which has previously had the app will be able to download it again.